# Optim: InexactError: Int64(0.01) when using IPNewton

Tags: julia, mathematical-optimization

I have this code to optimise a function using the [`IPNewton` method](https://julianlsolvers.github.io/Optim.jl/stable/#examples/generated/ipnewton_basics/) (`error.jl`):

```
import Optim

"""
Generate a matrix of constants used in computation
"""
function get_const(x::Vector{Float64}, sigma::Vector{Float64})::Array{Float64, 2}
    exp.(-x'.^2 ./ (2 .* sigma.^2)) ./ (sigma .* sqrt(2 * π))
end

# Log likelihood for mixture model
log_likelihood(p, C::Array{Float64, 2}) = sum(log.(p' * C))

"""
Constraint: all probabilities (ps) must sum to 1
"""
function constraint!(c, ps)::typeof(c)
    c[1] = sum(ps)
    c
end

N = 100
x = range(-1, 1, length=1000) |> collect
sigma = range(0.001, 2, length=N) |> collect

C = get_const(x, sigma)

constraints = Optim.TwiceDifferentiableConstraints(
    constraint!,
    fill(0, N), fill(1, N), # 0 <= (each probability) <= 1
    fill(1, N), fill(1, N)  # 1 <= constraint(p) <= 1 (probabilities sum to 1)
)
p0 = fill(1, N) / N # initial guess == equal probabilities

res = Optim.optimize(
    ps -> -log_likelihood(ps, C), # want to MAXIMIZE, so negate
    constraints, p0,
    Optim.IPNewton()
)
```

`Project.toml`:

```
[deps]
Optim = "429524aa-4258-5aef-a3af-852621145aeb"
```

Julia version:

```
forcebru@thing ~/test> julia --version
julia version 1.5.3
```

Error message:

```
forcebru@thing ~/test> julia error.jl
ERROR: LoadError: InexactError: Int64(0.01)
Stacktrace:
 [1] Int64 at ./float.jl:710 [inlined]
 [2] convert at ./number.jl:7 [inlined]
 [3] setindex! at ./array.jl:847 [inlined]
 [4] _unsafe_copyto!(::Array{Int64,1}, ::Int64, ::Array{Float64,1}, ::Int64, ::Int64) at ./array.jl:257
 [5] unsafe_copyto! at ./array.jl:311 [inlined]
 [6] _copyto_impl! at ./array.jl:335 [inlined]
 [7] copyto! at ./array.jl:321 [inlined]
 [8] copyto! at ./array.jl:347 [inlined]
 [9] finite_difference_jacobian!(::Array{Float64,2}, ::typeof(constraint!), ::Array{Float64,1}, ::FiniteDiff.JacobianCache{Array{Int64,1},Array{Int64,1},Array{Int64,1},UnitRange{Int64},Nothing,Val{:central}(),Int64}, ::Nothing; relstep::Float64, absstep::Float64, colorvec::UnitRange{Int64}, sparsity::Nothing, dir::Bool) at /Users/forcebru/.julia/packages/FiniteDiff/jLwWI/src/jacobians.jl:338
 [10] finite_difference_jacobian!(::Array{Float64,2}, ::Function, ::Array{Float64,1}, ::FiniteDiff.JacobianCache{Array{Int64,1},Array{Int64,1},Array{Int64,1},UnitRange{Int64},Nothing,Val{:central}(),Int64}, ::Nothing) at /Users/forcebru/.julia/packages/FiniteDiff/jLwWI/src/jacobians.jl:334 (repeats 2 times)
 [11] jac! at /Users/forcebru/.julia/packages/NLSolversBase/QPnui/src/objective_types/constraints.jl:298 [inlined]
 [12] initial_state(::Optim.IPNewton{typeof(Optim.backtrack_constrained_grad),Symbol}, ::Optim.Options{Float64,Nothing}, ::NLSolversBase.TwiceDifferentiable{Float64,Array{Float64,1},Array{Float64,2},Array{Float64,1}}, ::NLSolversBase.TwiceDifferentiableConstraints{typeof(constraint!),NLSolversBase.var"#jac!#126"{typeof(constraint!),FiniteDiff.JacobianCache{Array{Int64,1},Array{Int64,1},Array{Int64,1},UnitRange{Int64},Nothing,Val{:central}(),Int64}},NLSolversBase.var"#con_hess!#130"{Int64,Array{Int64,2},Array{Int64,3},NLSolversBase.var"#jac_vec!#129"{Int64,Int64},FiniteDiff.JacobianCache{Array{Int64,1},Array{Int64,1},Array{Int64,1},UnitRange{Int64},Nothing,Val{:central}(),Int64}},Int64}, ::Array{Float64,1}) at /Users/forcebru/.julia/packages/Optim/D7azp/src/multivariate/solvers/constrained/ipnewton/ipnewton.jl:135
 [13] optimize(::NLSolversBase.TwiceDifferentiable{Float64,Array{Float64,1},Array{Float64,2},Array{Float64,1}}, ::NLSolversBase.TwiceDifferentiableConstraints{typeof(constraint!),NLSolversBase.var"#jac!#126"{typeof(constraint!),FiniteDiff.JacobianCache{Array{Int64,1},Array{Int64,1},Array{Int64,1},UnitRange{Int64},Nothing,Val{:central}(),Int64}},NLSolversBase.var"#con_hess!#130"{Int64,Array{Int64,2},Array{Int64,3},NLSolversBase.var"#jac_vec!#129"{Int64,Int64},FiniteDiff.JacobianCache{Array{Int64,1},Array{Int64,1},Array{Int64,1},UnitRange{Int64},Nothing,Val{:central}(),Int64}},Int64}, ::Array{Float64,1}, ::Optim.IPNewton{typeof(Optim.backtrack_constrained_grad),Symbol}, ::Optim.Options{Float64,Nothing}) at /Users/forcebru/.julia/packages/Optim/D7azp/src/multivariate/solvers/constrained/ipnewton/interior.jl:228
 [14] optimize(::Function, ::NLSolversBase.TwiceDifferentiableConstraints{typeof(constraint!),NLSolversBase.var"#jac!#126"{typeof(constraint!),FiniteDiff.JacobianCache{Array{Int64,1},Array{Int64,1},Array{Int64,1},UnitRange{Int64},Nothing,Val{:central}(),Int64}},NLSolversBase.var"#con_hess!#130"{Int64,Array{Int64,2},Array{Int64,3},NLSolversBase.var"#jac_vec!#129"{Int64,Int64},FiniteDiff.JacobianCache{Array{Int64,1},Array{Int64,1},Array{Int64,1},UnitRange{Int64},Nothing,Val{:central}(),Int64}},Int64}, ::Array{Float64,1}, ::Optim.IPNewton{typeof(Optim.backtrack_constrained_grad),Symbol}, ::Optim.Options{Float64,Nothing}; inplace::Bool, autodiff::Symbol) at /Users/forcebru/.julia/packages/Optim/D7azp/src/multivariate/optimize/interface.jl:148
 [15] optimize(::Function, ::NLSolversBase.TwiceDifferentiableConstraints{typeof(constraint!),NLSolversBase.var"#jac!#126"{typeof(constraint!),FiniteDiff.JacobianCache{Array{Int64,1},Array{Int64,1},Array{Int64,1},UnitRange{Int64},Nothing,Val{:central}(),Int64}},NLSolversBase.var"#con_hess!#130"{Int64,Array{Int64,2},Array{Int64,3},NLSolversBase.var"#jac_vec!#129"{Int64,Int64},FiniteDiff.JacobianCache{Array{Int64,1},Array{Int64,1},Array{Int64,1},UnitRange{Int64},Nothing,Val{:central}(),Int64}},Int64}, ::Array{Float64,1}, ::Optim.IPNewton{typeof(Optim.backtrack_constrained_grad),Symbol}, ::Optim.Options{Float64,Nothing}) at /Users/forcebru/.julia/packages/Optim/D7azp/src/multivariate/optimize/interface.jl:147 (repeats 2 times)
 [16] top-level scope at /Users/forcebru/test/error.jl:27
 [17] include(::Function, ::Module, ::String) at ./Base.jl:380
 [18] include(::Module, ::String) at ./Base.jl:368
 [19] exec_options(::Base.JLOptions) at ./client.jl:296
 [20] _start() at ./client.jl:506
in expression starting at /Users/forcebru/test/error.jl:27
forcebru@thing ~/test [1]>
```

So... `InexactError: Int64(0.01)`? And it also seems to originate from within `Optim`?

I understand that `InexactError` here means that Julia couldn't convert `0.01` to an integer, which makes sense. But I have no idea where that `0.01` even came from! <strike>How to find out where to originated?</strike> What's wrong with this code and what can be done to fix this?

---

EDIT: I noticed that the `0.01` must be an element of `p0 = fill(1, N) / N` because if I set `N = 50`, the error becomes `InexactError: Int64(0.02)`, where `0.02 == 1/N`. But why is it attempting to convert it to an integer??

Answer (score 2):

After some intense looking at these parts of the error message:

```
 [8] copyto! at ./array.jl:347 [inlined]
 [9] finite_difference_jacobian!(::Array{Float64,2}, ::typeof(constraint!), ::Array{Float64,1}, ::FiniteDiff.JacobianCache{Array{Int64,1},Array{Int64,1},Array{Int64,1},UnitRange{Int64},Nothing,Val{:central}(),Int64}, ::Nothing; relstep::Float64, absstep::Float64, colorvec::UnitRange{Int64}, sparsity::Nothing, dir::Bool) at /Users/forcebru/.julia/packages/FiniteDiff/jLwWI/src/jacobians.jl:338
 ...
 [15] optimize(::Function, ::NLSolversBase.TwiceDifferentiableConstraints{typeof(constraint!),NLSolversBase.var"#jac!#126"{typeof(constraint!),FiniteDiff.JacobianCache{Array{Int64,1},Array{Int64,1},Array{Int64,1},UnitRange{Int64},Nothing,Val{:central}(),Int64}},NLSolversBase.var"#con_hess!#130"{Int64,Array{Int64,2},Array{Int64,3},NLSolversBase.var"#jac_vec!#129"{Int64,Int64},FiniteDiff.JacobianCache{Array{Int64,1},Array{Int64,1},Array{Int64,1},UnitRange{Int64},Nothing,Val{:central}(),Int64}},Int64}, ::Array{Float64,1}, ::Optim.IPNewton{typeof(Optim.backtrack_constrained_grad),Symbol}, ::Optim.Options{Float64,Nothing}) at /Users/forcebru/.julia/packages/Optim/D7azp/src/multivariate/optimize/interface.jl:147 (repeats 2 times)
 [16] top-level scope at /Users/forcebru/test/error.jl:27
```

...I saw that the `FiniteDiff.JacobianCache` for the *constraints* was inferred to be parametrised over `Int64`:

```
FiniteDiff.JacobianCache{
    Array{Int64,1},
    Array{Int64,1},
    Array{Int64,1},
    UnitRange{Int64},
    Nothing,
    Val{:central}(),
    Int64
}
```

...which is pretty odd because I clearly want to optimise over the reals.

Turns out that in this part of the code:

```
constraints = Optim.TwiceDifferentiableConstraints(
    constraint!,
    fill(0, N), fill(1, N), # 0 <= (each probability) <= 1
    fill(1, N), fill(1, N)  # 1 <= constraint(p) <= 1 (probabilities sum to 1)
)
```

the `fill(0, N)` and friends are *all integers*, because `0` is an integer. Looks like this lead to that attempted conversion from float to integer.

I changed this code to read:

```
constraints = Optim.TwiceDifferentiableConstraints(
    constraint!,
    fill(0., N), fill(1., N), # 0 <= (each probability) <= 1
    fill(1., N), fill(1., N)  # 1 <= constraint(p) <= 1 (probabilities sum to 1)
)
```

...and now there's no error (the algorithm doesn't converge, though, but that's a different problem).

Comment: It would be good to open an issue noting such things. Optim should probably call `float(x)` somewhere to sanitise such input.

Comment: @mcabbott, actually, I initially started writing this as an issue, but then thought I was just missing something simple because I'm very new to Julia, so asked here instead. Indeed, an error that originates in the depths of a library looks like a bug in the library itself.

Comment: Bug might be too strong a word, but it would be a friendly thing to catch & correct integer input, rather than failing. The reason you get a failure from deep inside is that types are often left generic, so that it can happily specialise on other weird numbers.